# Is there a way that I can add the ColumnDefinitions into the <grid>

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code looks like this:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <local:LabelBodyRendererClass HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Show Subcategory" YAlign="Center" XAlign="Center" />
   <Switch x:Name="swtSwitch" Grid.Column="1" Toggled="SwtSwitch" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
</Grid>
```

Is there a way that I can add the ColumnDefinitions into the  element?  My IDE is showing it's an option but I don't know how to specify them.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code above works, right?

Comment: Yes it works but I would like to know if I can have something like <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0" ColumnDefinitions .. >    In the IDE it gives ColumnDefinitions as something that is allowed in the <Grid> element tag.  I'm trying to simplify the code as much as possible and remove anything not needed. Note I did try a <SwitchCell> but from what I see I cannot change the padding on that and I want to pad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can define it as an attribute. And if you could, it would wreck your readability. Because `ColumnDefinition` is a complex type, you would have to type the string representation of it, as an array, inside an attribute.

If you want to clean your code, create your own, custom grid which has the columns predefined, but then you would have to expose views as properties, to fill your column. So, you would only save a few lines of the column definitions.